# Postgres - Where filter on value or custom default

Tags: postgresql

Assuming a `locale_info` table that stores multiple `items` for a given `locale`

```sql
CREATE TABLE locale_info (
  locale TEXT,
  item_id TEXT
)
```

What is the cleanest way to select items for a given `search_locale` OR a default `locale` if table has no entries for the given `search_locale`?

I'm using the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM locale_info
WHERE locale = COALESCE(
  (SELECT DISTINCT (locale) FROM locale_info WHERE locale = 'en_ZA'), 
  'en'
);
```

which will return `en_ZA` items if there are any, else the default `en` locale.

My question is: How do I rewrite that rather ugly query in a cleaner Postgres fashion?

Comment: The clean way is to execute two queries, the second one only if the first one returns no result.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Appreciate the tip!

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of, is to use a UNION ALL, where the second part is only run if the first returned a row:

```
with requested as (
  SELECT *
  FROM locale_info
  WHERE locale = 'en_ZA'
)
select *
from requested
union all
SELECT *
FROM locale_info
where locale = 'en'
  and not exists (select * from requested);
```

Another option is to always select both locales but sort them by "importance" and discard the second one:

```
select *
from locale_info
where locale in ('en_ZA', 'en')
order by locale = 'en_ZA' desc
limit 1;
```

When sorting booleans, `false` is sorted before `true`, so by sorting DESCending, the row that contains the required locale comes first.

In any case, you should have an index on the `locale` column (or an index where that column is the first column)

Comment: The first option is very interesting, and I'm already considering ways to integrate into my other queries. Thanks for your ceaseless effort on the Postgres front.